# Return or Collect value while iterating via Hashmap using java8

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

Following is the traditional code to check some condition and update a variable.

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer> testMap= new HashMap<>();
int pair = 0;
for(Integer value: testMap.values()){
        pair = pair+value/2;
}
```

How the same thing can be achieved using java8 streams or lambdas?

Comment: I don't see any condition here.

Comment: ...and what did you try?

Comment: I did mentioned what I tried, and I hope I was clear on my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stream` the `Map` values, transform them, then `sum()`

```
int pair = testMap.values().stream().mapToInt(i -> i / 2).sum();
```

---

To make it look a bit more like your original code, you can use a `reduce()` operation:

```
int pair = testMap.values()
                  .stream()
                  .reduce(0, (p, i) -> p + i / 2);
```

Basically this starts with the value `0` (the "identity") and then passes the result of applying the reduction function as input, along with the current value, to each value in turn.

---

P.S. program to the interface:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> testMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Thanks @nullpointer. Will now do the whole lot boxed, but I suppose that's not too much of an issue.

Comment: @nullpointer the `mapToInt` means that the reduction is done with `int`. Without it the reduction will happen with `Integer` and be unboxed at the end. That means quite a lot of boxing and unboxing during calculation.

Comment: Or `int pair = testMap.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum() / 2;`

Comment: @Holger the results would differ due to integer division.

Comment: Well, yes, if there are odd values. If that’s the case, it would be a very interesting question, which result is actually intended for the particular use case.

Comment: Fair point @Holger. I just replicated the result the OPs code currently produces.